# EntityFramework Error 26 with LocalDb and IndentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a DataAccess C# class library for an MVC application. Inside of the class library, I am using EntityFramework and ASP.NET Identity.

When I try to run **Update-Database** or **Add-Migration** on the class library, I get an error.

`Error 26:A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.`

My UserAccount class derived from IdentityUser is below:

```
public class UserAccount : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
        public virtual PaymentDetail PaymentDetail { get; set; }

        public virtual MediaResource ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
    }
```

The implementation of my context class uses this constructor:

```
public class LouderContext : IdentityDbContext<UserAccount>
    {

        public LouderContext("DefaultConnection") { }
```

The contents of my App.config file are below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Things that I have tried:

1. Changing the parameter of the connection factory to `mssqllocaldb` or `v12.0` from `v11.0`
2. Repairing my visual studio installation
3. Manually adding the connection string from the SQL Server Object Explorer into a connectionstring object in App.config

I can access (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB from SSMS without issue. I can also access LocalDb through a scaffolded MVC project but my issue persists whenever I try to run any commands on my class library via the package manager console. What seems to be the issue? Does anything obvious jump out?

Comment: You don't have a "DefaultConnection" which you are passing to base class constructor of `LouderContext ` in your config file.

Comment: Thanks, but I removed it and the issue still exists.

Comment: Then add a "DefaultConnection" to your config file :). `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: I added base("DefaultConnection") back to the context and added the connection string but I am still getting Error 26. I also tried changing the connection to the actual connectionstring "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" but it is still having issues.

Comment: Can you post your updated app.config with the connection string?

Comment: Yep, I just replaced the old app.config in the question with the new one.

Comment: Try `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=asp-net_test;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` first to see if we can get past the error...if this works, we can start putting some of those other pieces back.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I'm really lost, haha.

Comment: It was working before?  Has anything changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF use the start project as source of the connection string , i think it might be your problem as your start project is the MVC Project try to change the start project to be the class library and then add migration and update-database  .

**Edit :** 
You have two  connection strings with the same name DefaultConnection one at the app.config and one at web.config , change that and in DBContext constructor add the one belongs to app.config Ex :  `public LouderContext("AppConfigConnection") { }`

another solution :

```
Get-Help enable-migrations -detailed
```

You can find this documentation for the -StartupProjectName option:

```
-StartUpProjectName
```

> ```
> Specifies the configuration file to use for named connection strings. If
> omitted, the specified project's configuration file is used.
> ```

It means that if you use this option to specify a project name, migrations will look for the connection string in the config file of the specified project. (The config file can be web.config or app.config).

Comment: Nice Ahmed!  Didn't see the class library comment.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick. Is there any way that I can get it to work without specifying an explicit connection string?

Comment: You have two  connection strings with the same name DefaultConnection one at the app.config and one at web.config , change that and in DBContext constructor add the one belongs to app.config EX :  public LouderContext("AppConfigConnection") { } ,i will edit my answer with another solution  .

Answer (score 0):

Either leave your Context constructor blank( i.e. don't call base()), or make sure there is a connectionstring entry in the app.config for `DefaultConnection`.

Comment: This should be a comment :)

Comment: Thanks but after modifying it, the issue still exists.

Comment: Well the tour said use comments to clarify or ask for more information.  New users can't even add comments.  Please point me to some resource that says that and I'll gladly comply.